# bitmask vpn: Could not find a polkit authentication agent. Please run one and try again

Tags: vpn

On elementary OS juno I tried to connect to bitmask vpn but it shows me this error: Could not find a polkit authentication agent. Please run one and try again.

and I don't know what should i do, please help me...